# No está funcionando correctamente NotificationCompat

Tags: android, rest, firebase

Que tal bueno es algo extraño pero no puedo mostrar mi notificationCompat..
ahora tengo el mensaje tranquilamente lo veo ya que lo muestro en el LOG, pero es algo extraño y no he encontrado la manera para poder mostrarlo.
Estoy usando Firebase.
La clase dónde se encuentra mi servicio es

```
public class MyFcmListenerService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
public static final String TAG = MyFcmListenerService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG,"HECHO");
    Log.d(TAG,remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    if (Test.getTest(1).isEstado_token()) {
        Log.d(TAG,"bolean1"+String.valueOf(Test.getTest(1).isEstado_token()));
        mostrarMensaje(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    }

}

private void mostrarMensaje(String mensaje) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(Constantes.PREFERENCIA_PARA_PREGUNTAS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int pre_token_count = preferences.getInt(Constantes.KEY_IDENTIFICADOR, 0);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, PrincipalActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("TEST")
            .setContentText(mensaje)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000});

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(pre_token_count, builder.build());

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    pre_token_count++;
    editor.putInt(Constantes.KEY_IDENTIFICADOR, pre_token_count);
    editor.commit();

}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que mensaje obtiene en el LogCat? Antes funcionaba ahora no?

Comment: @Elenasys que tal en el Log veo el mensaje que mando desde mi server mi problema es que mi notificación no se muestra.. creo haber olvidado alguna configuración por que tengo una app donde si funca las notificaciones con firebase u.u

Comment: Llega la notificación en public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) { ? También asegura que tu dispositivo esta registrado para recibirlas, en ocasiones el token no funciona y tienes que asegurar tener uno valido.

Comment: @Elenasys si acabo de agregar una imagen con los datos de mi log.. por el momento de prueba mi mensaje es "Bien joven xd", lo siento pero es una prueba y no se me ocurrió otro mensaje.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado*

A Notification object must contain the following:

-A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()/ una pequeña imagen para mostrar

-A title, set by setContentTitle()/ un titulo para nuestra notificación

-Detail text, set by setContentText() y un contenido de texto para nuestra notificación

Para trabajar con notificaciones se requiere de estos 3 campos.. mi error estaba en que había olvidado agregarle un ícono a mi notificación u.u

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required